# jQuery двигать скролл бар в обратном направлении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, на писал скрипт, который при клике двигает скролл бар в перед,
подскажите как можно сделать чтобы он мог двигаться в о обратном направлении.

```
<ul class="example">
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
</ul>

<div class="scroll-bar">
 <div class="track-bar">
   <div class="drag"></div>
 </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.example li').click(function(){
    $('.drag').animate({left : '+=25' + '%' });
  });
});
```

Код: https://jsfiddle.net/justmake88/eau63zxp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var itemCount = $('.example li').length;
  var partSize = Math.round(100 / itemCount);
  $('.example li').click(function() {
    var itemIndex = $(this).index();
    $('.drag').animate({
      left: itemIndex * partSize + '%'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.example {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.example li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
}
.scroll-bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1px;
  top: 15px;
}
.track-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.drag {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="example">
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
  <li>example</li>
</ul>

<div class="scroll-bar">
  <div class="track-bar">
    <div class="drag"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```